# PHP foreach loop failing on $_POST

Tags: php

I am wanting to iterate through an array in POST, but my code is failing to enter the loop...

```
echo var_dump($_POST['pizza']);
    foreach($_POST['pizza'] as $orderline) {
        $number = 2;
        echo "inside",
        $query = "INSERT INTO orderlines (itemID,orderID,quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($DBC, $query); //prepare the query
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $orderline, $orderID, $number);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        echo mysqli_error($DBC);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
```

The `echo "inside"` is just for debugging to show that I have got inside the loop, which I am not.  The initial `var_dump($_POST['pizza')` is for debugging to see that there is infact an array with values.  The array does exist, but the echo fails to execute; hence I am not inside the loop and I am failing to see why.

Much thanks

Comment: So it's not an array. Can you paste your `var_dump` output?  Maybe it's a string. Also `echo "inside",` shouldn't have comma at the end.

Comment: Thanks IT goldman, you got me on the right path, I needed to change the name of the input from name="pizza" to name="pizza[]"

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, thanks to IT goldman for the clue.

Changed the name attribute of the input from pizza to pizza[] and boom we are in business.